# how do I get date in mongoose same as I type it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

for my practice project, I am working on a barber app with react and nodejs.For the input form in my React I got the date as what I type, when I console.log() it gives me

```
date: '2020-01-24',
```

but when I fetch from by back end I am getting it as

```
date: 2020-01-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

I only need the year month and date how could I do that

back end model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema(
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  time: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    default: ""
  }
},
{
  timestamps: true
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

route/feed.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { body } = require("express-validator");
const router = express.Router();
const feedController = require("../controllers/feed");
router.post(
  "/feed",
  feedController.createFeed
);
```

controller/feed.js

```
const Post = require("../models/post");
//const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
//const stripe = require("stripe")();

exports.createFeed = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const age = req.body.age;
  const date = req.body.date;
  const time = req.body.time;
  const content = req.body.content;
  const price = req.body.price;
  console.log(date, time);

  const post = new Post({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    age: age,
    date: date,
    time: time,
    content: content,
    price: price
  });

  post
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        messege: "created succesfully",
        posts: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

how could I only get what I type in the date field?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening just because of type that you placed in your `schema`. Inside your `schema` you have type `Date` of that field `date`. SO when `mongodb` saves the document so it converts your `string` into `Date` whose default pattern is the same in which you are receiving back `date` from `db`.

Option-1 :

So if you really want to get the date as it is as you entered from client so just convert your type to `String` inside your `schema` like this

```
date: {
type: String,
required: true
```

}

Option-2:

Another way of achieving your desired pattern is that keep the type `Date` inside your schema. But when you receive the date like this `2020-01-24T00:00:00.000Z` so convert that date manually on client side`(react.js)` like this

```
function formatDate(date) {
var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) 
    month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) 
    day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```